Opencv library version mismatch in Snapcraft Enviroment
I installed the latest version of opencv library on my desktop :
pkg-config --modversion opencv4
4.6.0
and created a c++ camera_video_feed_display application using these
OPENCV_LIBS = -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui
and this application is running properly further when I am converting this into a snap , I am using these available stage packages in snapcraft enviroment for my yaml file
ip-camera-feed:
source: .
plugin: make
build-packages:
  - libopencv-dev
stage-packages:
  - libopencv-core4.5d
  - libopencv-imgcodecs4.5d
  - libopencv-videoio4.5d
  - libopencv-highgui4.5d

after running snapcraft command I am getting these warnings

library: usr/local/bin/ip_camera_feed: missing dependency 'libopencv_core.so.406'. (https://snapcraft.io/docs/linters-library)
library: usr/local/bin/ip_camera_feed: missing dependency 'libopencv_highgui.so.406'. (https://snapcraft.io/docs/linters-library)
library: usr/local/bin/ip_camera_feed: missing dependency 'libopencv_videoio.so.406'. (https://snapcraft.io/docs/linters-library)

Is this a opencv version mismatch issue while converting it into a snap?
Which opencv version should I use while building a c++ application then further converting it into a snap for ubuntu core?
